# Given lat, lon and heading, compute tangential 3D vector

Tags: geolocation, geo

Assume, I have a 3D unit-sphere model, I compute a 3D point with

```
x = cos(lat) * cos(lon)
y = cos(lat) * sin(lon)
z = sin(lat)
```

Now assume that I have given a compass bearing in degrees, where 0 means bearing towards true north (lat=90°).

How can I compute the 3D bearing-vector orthogonal to [x, y, z], i.e. tangent vector looking towards the compass bearing.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a point P with geodetic coordinates lat,lon and cartesian coordinates x,y,z. Another handy coordinate system is the topocentric one, centred at P: (u,v,w) where u is positive towards the north, v positive to the east and w positive to up along the normal to the tangent plane at P.

The topocentric and cartesian coordinates are related by

```
(u) = M*(X-x)
(v) =   (Y-y)
(w) =   (Z-z)
where
M = ( 1  0 0) * Ry(lat-90) * Rz(lon-180)
    ( 0 -1 0)
    ( 0  0 1)
and Ry is the usual 3d rotation about the y axis etc
```

or going the other way

```
(X) = (x) + N*(u)
(Y)   (y) +   (v)
(Z)   (z) +   (w)
where
N = Rz(180-lon)*Ry(90-lat)*(1  0 0)
                          (0 -1 0)
                          (0  0 1)
```

In topocentric cordinates the unit vector at a compass angle c would be

```
( cos(c))
( sin(c))
( 0     )
```

and if you apply N above to this you'll get the corresponding vector in cartesians.

Answer (score 0):

To define the problem, let say that we have a point *Po = (Xo, Yo,
Zo)* on the unit sphere and we want to find the tangent to *Po*
oriented towards the pole *N = (0, 0, 1)*.

My solution uses a parametric description of said tangent, using an
auxiliary variable *a*, *P = P(a)*.

[image: The geometry of the problem]

In the figure above we have

- an horizontal section of the unit sphere at *Z=0* (left) where you
  can see the point *(Xo, Yo, 0)* and the *a* axis: for convenience *a
  = 0* in the centre and *a = 1* in (Xo, Yo, 0);
- a vertical section of the unit sphere  (right) passing for *Po*,
  *(0, 0, 0)* and *(0, 0, 1)* — in the bottom you can see the *a*
  axis — in this section we see also the requested tangent line, that
  passes for *Po* and the point *(0, 0, Zp)* where, by similarity of
  triangles, it is *Zp = 1/Zo*.

In code, assuming you have a `Point` class of some sort in your
backpack,

```
def P_tan(a, Po):
    Xo, Yo, Zo = Po
    Xp, Yp, Zp = 0, 0, 1/Zo
    X = Xp + a*(Xo-Xp)         # X(0)=Xp, X(1)=Xo
    Y = Yp + a*(Yo-Tp)         # Y(0)=Yp, Y(1)=Yo
    Z = Zp + a*(Zo-Zp)         # Z(0)=Zp, Z(1)=Zo
    return Point(X, Y, Z)
```

If we were more interested in the components of the tangent versor

```
def tan_versor(Po):
    Xo, Yo, Zo = Po
    Xp, Yp, Zp = 0, 0, 1/Zo
    dX, dY, dZ = Xp-Xo, Yp-Yo, Zp-Zo 
    length = sqrt(dX**2+dY**2+dZ**2)
    return dX/length, dY/length, dZ/length,
```

Please note that the oriented line goes outwards, while the versor
goes towards the nearest pole (due to *Zo* having a sign…).  Last but
not least, you need to special-case for *Zo=0*.